# How can Android Studio launch the inline fun <T> key()?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from the offical sample project [here](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/home/HomeScreens.kt).

The Code B is from Android Studio source code.

I have searched the article about the function `key` by Google, but I can't find more details about it.

How can Android Studio launch `the inline fun <T> key()`?  Why can't the author use Code C to launch directly?

**Code A**

```
key(detailPost.id) {
    LazyColumn(
        state = detailLazyListState,
        contentPadding = contentPadding,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .notifyInput {
                onInteractWithDetail(detailPost.id)
            }
    ) {
        stickyHeader {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            PostTopBar(
                isFavorite = hasPostsUiState.favorites.contains(detailPost.id),
                onToggleFavorite = { onToggleFavorite(detailPost.id) },
                onSharePost = { sharePost(detailPost, context) },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().wrapContentWidth(Alignment.End)
            )
        }
        postContentItems(detailPost)
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
inline fun <T> key(
    @Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")
    vararg keys: Any?,
    block: @Composable () -> T
) = block()
```

**Code C**

```
LazyColumn(
    state = detailLazyListState,
    contentPadding = contentPadding,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .notifyInput {
            onInteractWithDetail(detailPost.id)
        }
) {
    stickyHeader {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        PostTopBar(
            isFavorite = hasPostsUiState.favorites.contains(detailPost.id),
            onToggleFavorite = { onToggleFavorite(detailPost.id) },
            onSharePost = { sharePost(detailPost, context) },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().wrapContentWidth(Alignment.End)
        )
    }
    postContentItems(detailPost)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `key` documentation:

> `key` is a utility composable that is used to "group" or "key" a block of execution inside of a composition. This is sometimes needed for correctness inside of control-flow that may cause a given composable invocation to execute more than once during composition.

It also contains several examples, so [check it out](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#key(kotlin.Array,kotlin.Function0)).

Here is a basic example of the usefulness of it. Suppose you have the following Composable. I added [`DisposableEffect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary?hl=vi#DisposableEffect(kotlin.Any,kotlin.Function1)) to track its lifecycle.

```
@Composable
fun SomeComposable(text: String) {
    DisposableEffect(text) {
        println("appear $text")
        onDispose {
            println("onDispose $text")
        }
    }
    Text(text)
}
```

And here's usage:

```
val items = remember { List(10) { it } }
var offset by remember {
    mutableStateOf(0)
}
Button(onClick = {
    println("click")
    offset += 1
}) {
}
Column {
    items.subList(offset, offset + 3).forEach { item ->
        key(item) {
            SomeComposable(item.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

I only display two list items, and move the window each time the button is clicked.

Without `key`, each click will remove all previous views and create new ones.

But with `key(item)`, only the disappeared item disappears, and the items that are still on the screen are reused without recomposition.

Here are the logs:

```
appear 0
appear 1
appear 2
click
onDispose 0
appear 3
click
onDispose 1
appear 4
click
onDispose 2
appear 5
```