# Redundant recomposition happenning in my layout. Why does it recompose even though inputs haven't changed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have a SnapshotStateMap that I use to track updates in my layout, this map is stored in a viewmodel.

This the site call:

```
    val roundState = viewModel.roundState
    for (index in 0 until attempts) {
        val state = roundState[index] ?: WordState.Empty
        Row {
            RoundWord(state, letters)
        }
    }
```

In my program there are changes to only one item at the time, so basically my train of thought is:
I add a new state or update the old in map -> I pass it to RoundWord -> If there is no state for index I pass in empty state -> RoundWord Composable relies on state to display the needed UI.

Here is the body of RoundWord

```
@Composable 
private fun RoundWord(
state: WordState,
letters: Int,
) {
when (state) {
    is WordState.Progress -> ProgressWord(letters)
    is WordState.Empty -> WordCells(letters)
    is WordState.Resolved -> WordCells(letters) { WiPLetter(state.value.word[it]) }
    }
}
```

From what I understand if there is no state in roundState map for a given index I provide Empty state that is defined as an object in a sealed interface hierarchy. Same object -> no recomposition. But for some reason it recomposes every time. I have been at this for a few days now and despite going though tons of documentation I can't see what I am missing here. Why does this recomposition happens for empty state?

Comment: Have you thought about doing nothing if there is an EmptyState?

Comment: Sure, thanks for suggestion but it doesn't work for me. Firstly, I still have a UI to display even for empty state. Secondly, I asked this question to understand what exactly happens under the hood to produce this behavior. Is this intentional or not?

Comment: Start with [key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69694528/3585796) for each row - you need to provide a unique identifier. If this didn't help, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: "in a sealed interface hierarchy" - annotated as @Stable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordState sealed class hierarchy contained a property of type `List<T>`. Compose does not consider List to be a stable type so the signature was actually something like `unstable words: List<String>`.

> Compose compiler cannot be completely sure that collections such as List, Map, and Set are truly immutable and therefore marks them as unstable

There are a few solutions for this problem

- It's possible to wrap List type in a `@Stable` annotated class. This should work as long as you adhere to `@Stable` contract.
- Use Kotlinx Immutable Collections (They look to be abandoned)
- Use `SnapshotStateList` that is considered stable

I think the best option is to provide a [stability configuration file](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/stability/fix#configuration-file) which makes it possible to annotate all Kotlin collections as stable. This works as long as you respect stability contract which just happens to basically be a set of good practices.